# Ruby on rails database schema help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, schema, migration

Hay guys, I'm a novice to intermediate RoR programmer. However, I'm not too good on setting up relational database's so i need a hand.

Basically my app is a book club. A user signs up, the user creates a book club based on a book. Other users joins this club and discusses it (like a forum).

I have written a english description of the schema.

> **User** has many clubs
>
> **Club** has one book, has many users, has many threads
>
> **Book** has many clubs, belongs to a club
>
> **Threads** has many replies, belongs to a club
>
> **Reply** belongs to a thread

I need some help with the migrations for this, aswell as the models.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the best descriptions of Active Record associations I've seen:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Go through these and you'll see how to setup your models and migrations.